# Rendering list from list of arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've got an app where by clicking on a button i'm adding data from the randomuser api to my array and then rendering it as a list.

```
   const onClickHandler = () => {
     axios.get("https://api.randomuser.me/")
     .then(res => {
        const data = res.data.results["0"]
        setPosts(data)
        addHistory(prevInputState => ([...prevInputState,data.name.first]))
        console.log(data)
     })
   }

   const[posts,setPosts] = useState([])
   const[history,addHistory] = useState([])
```

In this case Im loading entire dataset into "posts" and first name into "history"

then i'm able to render a list of all first names fetched using :

```
{history.map((name)=> (
  <Item> {name} </Item>
))}
```

This works well when im only saving first name from the data into the "history" state . How would I proceed if i wanted to store entire data ( not data.name.first ) and then use list to retrieve the same list of first names?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your addHistory function, could you just replace data.name.first with data? Then you'd pass the entire object into the history, and can access all of its fields in your later calls.

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
     axios.get("https://api.randomuser.me/")
     .then(res => {
        const data = res.data.results["0"]
        setPosts(data)
        addHistory(prevInputState => ([...prevInputState,data]))
        console.log(data)
     })
   }

   const[posts,setPosts] = useState([])
   const[history,addHistory] = useState([])
```

Then,

```
{history.map((data)=> (
  <Item> {data.name.first} </Item>
))}
```

access whatever other object fields you may need.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping a seperate state for history, can't you just use the existing posts state to iterate and access the relevent data?

```
{posts.map((data)=> (
    <Item> {data.name.first} </Item>
  ))}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, because posts doesnt keep the history..every button click posts is replaced by a new person.